# Parsing a CSV from a Mail (Gmail) with double quotes and ? characters with Google Apps Script

Tags: csv, parsing, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I did set up routines with the following code to parse CSVs into specific spreadsheets:

```
 function updateGmvAndNmv() {
  const threads = GmailApp.search("from:(sender@xxx.de) subject:(uniqueHeader)");
  const messages = threads[0].getMessages();
  const length = messages.length;
  const lastMessage = messages[length - 1];
  const attachemnt = lastMessage.getAttachments()[0];

  const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachemnt.getDataAsString(), ",");

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID").getSheetByName("sheetName")
  const ssOriginalRange = ss.getRange("A:E");
  const ssToPaste = ss.getRange(1,1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length);

  ssOriginalRange.clear();
  ssToPaste.setValues(csvData)
}
```

With the latest CSV that I want to parse, I encounter an issue, where I am stuck. I tried to play around with the settings in the app that sends me the report but I can not change the way the CSV is being constructed. When I look at the CSV with a text Editor, I see something like this:

```
GMV and NMV per partner

"Merchant",,"NMV","GMV bef Cancellation","GMV bef Return"
```

When I let the above code run, it gets the file and outputs the following in my spreadsheet:
[Spreadsheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYPft.png)

Which brings up the following questions:

1. Why do I have "" (double quotes) in row 5? I assumed the parseCsv-function removes those.
2. With my other CSVs I did not have any issues, but there I did not have any double quotes. Can someone explain the difference in CSVs, once with double quotes and once without?
3. How can I treat this data correctly, in order to get the data without the "" into the spreadsheet?
4. Why do I see some ? symbols (please look at the fx input field, row 1 and 7) and how do I get rid of them? The export should be without any format (CSV) and in a text editor I do see all values normally - without any ?.

Comment: Does your question have 4 questions?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, as I do not only want someone to give me a solution, but I am deeply interested into how it is working and what is going wrong. Could you support here? All these questions are linked to each other, hence they are asked in the same post. I numbered my questions in order to make it easier to refer to them. If I had just mentioned them in the text - like other people do - would that be better? :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, when I could correctly understand your 4 questions and I could think of 4 answers, I would like to post them as an answer.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for getting back. It would be very helpful to me to get answers to my questions. Please let me know if you need further information or explanation from my side to answer those question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample CSV data? In your showing script, I think that the sample CSV data is `attachemnt.getDataAsString()`. Or, can you provide the sample CSV file? In this case, I think that the sample CSV file is `lastMessage.getAttachments()[0]`.

Comment: @Tanaike The sample CSV is lastMessage.getAttachments()[0]. While parsing it, I need to use it as: attachemnt.getDataAsString(). How can I send you the sample csv? All file sharing sites I found are dodgy.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `All file sharing sites I found are dodgy.`, can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike all sites that I found where i can upload the sample csv do not seem very trustworthy. How can I share the sample csv with you?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, for example, how about sharing the file with Google Drive? But, even if you cannot do it, don't worry.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks. Please find the Google Drive link [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ALQoMBul2rua-JhI6t1aW7kO8yXMoqsc/view?usp=sharing). I can not share the complete CSV due to privacy reasons. I hope the CSV, after formatting it, still has the same errors :)

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing a sample CSV. When I tested your script using your provided CSV data, I couldn't replicate your situation. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue using your provided CSV data? I would be grateful if you can forgive my very poor skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the encoding. The correct encoding of the file is UTF-16, while the standard encoding of .getDataAsString() is UTF-8.